# Expandable listview with Edittext in Childview

Tags: android

**Adapter file.**

```
private TextInputLayout hint_code,hint_pass;

@Override
public  View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View v, final ViewGroup parent) {   
final Device device = (Device) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);  
    if (v == null)    {   
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );  
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_list, parent, false);    
}  
hint_code = (TextInputLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.hint_code);    
hint_pass = (TextInputLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.hint_password);    
final TextInputEditText   password1 = (TextInputEditText) v.findViewById(R.id.password1);    
final TextInputEditText   enter_code = (TextInputEditText) v.findViewById(R.id.pin_code);    

return v;    
}
```

**Below is Mainifest file code.**

```
<activity       
android:name=".MainActivity"    
android:launchMode="singleTask"    
android:noHistory="false"    
android:screenOrientation="portrait"    
android:theme="@style/Maintheme"    
android:isScrollContainer="false"        
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Above code is expandable listview. I used editext in childview but problem is that when I expand the group and click on edittext, it does not open the keyboard/keypad of Adnroid. edittext indicates that it is focused but keyboard is not displaying.

When group is by default expanded then when click on edittext that time keyboard is displaying properly but once I collpase the group and again expand, that time keyboard is not showing in childview.

Edit 01:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Pin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text="Set Your Pin"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/hint_code"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/grey_shade"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Pin"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/pin_code"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Your Device Pin"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
        android:drawableStart="@mipmap/password"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:maxLength="4"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```